# How to use java lambda expression for my customized runnable method

Tags: java, android, lambda

I define a class like this:

```
public class ResponseRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    public void runOnResponse(String response) {
    }
}
```

so when i want to use this class and `runOnResponse` method I want to show syntax like lambda expression, but it show me this:

```
 new ResponseRunnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void runOnResponse(String responseString) {
                            //dosomthing
                        }
                    }
```

but I interested in :

```
(response)->{dosomthing(response)}
```

**how can I this conversion to lambda expression?**

Comment: i dont think you can, dont think overrides work with lamdas

Comment: As @a_local_nobody said, you cannot implement/extend a class through lambdas, only functional interfaces can be implemented through lambdas. A remark on your code: if your `run`-method is empty, then do not implement `Runnable`.

Comment: thanks guys, So @Turing85 what if I remove run implement and just one method (runOnResponse) can I use lambda in this case?

Comment: No. Again: you cannot implement/extend classes through lambdas. Only functional interfaces. Look at [@blackr4y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233059/4216641) for details.

Comment: thank you @Turing85. I completely got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expression can be used only if you have one abstract method in the interface (called  functional interface). You can read more in official documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it, lambda expression can be applied for `functional interface`, `functional interface` is an interface with only **one** non default method.